# why are ads not showing up on my Rails app/website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, adsense

I'm basically trying to add in a simple ad banner code and another ad type cased in scripts but they are not showing up. I'm trying to put it into my `show.html.erb` view which is basically people's profiles.

Here's the full code showing where I'm trying to include the ad script. Do I need to put the code somewhere else?

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
}) 

</script>

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
       </h1>
      </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>

    </section>
  <br>
  </aside>


  <div class="span10">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.empty? %>
<h3>Profile</h3>
<% end %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Browse Text</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>

      </ol>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.URLofAdProvider.com/widget/11xxxxxxxx/"></script>         

    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* Ad1 */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

The two scripts at the bottom are the Ad scripts. I can't get either of them to show up. Anyone know why I can't display them?

Comment: You say the source of jQuery is `/jquery.js`. This means, for example, `http://example.com/jquery.js`. Is this the right path?

Comment: In addition to djthoms' suggestion, do the ads show up in an ordinary HTML page outside of Rails? It's possible an add-on is blocking them, or that the ad parameters are configured incorrectly.

Comment: that jQuery is for the facebox which is a lightbox (http://defunkt.io/facebox/). Can this lightbox be used with the ads?

Comment: @Dan Wich, I'm almost certain that the ad parameters are configured correctly. I just copied and pasted the codes directly from the websites

Comment: Ok. If you view-source on the output of your Rails page, does the JavaScript appear with the same output as you'd expect? And do you see any errors in your browser's error console?

Comment: When I did view-source in Firefox, the script codes look the same as how I included them into show.html.erb. One of them is repeated but I'm just trying to get any to display at the moment. I do not see any errors, but I do have a bunch of warnings (I think they were probably already present before I added the ad scripts though). There's one warning that says "Empty string passed to getElementByID() and it references a .js file

Comment: Can you insert your ad javascript into an empty HTML file and confirm they appear correctly there? If they don't, or if you continue to get errors in the console, you know that the problem is in the ad javascript rather than your site.

Comment: I did put both ad scripts in between <html><body></body></html> in an empty file and uploaded to my server, but I do not see neither ad displayed. Could it be something with the domain being https:// and not http://?

Comment: FYI, in the browser error console, I get this message for this empty HTML file that I created - "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range."